# Searching an array for a value but only printing the first instance[update]

Tags: java, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I am making a horse race program that will print the 1st 2nd and 3rd place horses. I have to set up the 10 horses in an array and then add random number from 1-3 to their position. The winner is the first horse to hit 15 or beyond.

My problem is that my program does not properly print the 2nd and 3rd place horses.

[UPDATE] I removed the many conditions and added string variables to store the information. It runs smoother but now I dont know why the program keeps printing duplicates and such.

Here is the code, I updated the `for` loop that was printing the winners:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HorseRace{
  public static void main(String[ ] arg){
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   int range = 3;
   int win = 15;
   final int SIZE = 5;
   Random ran = new Random( );
   boolean winner = false;
   boolean second = false;
   int[ ] arrRan = new int[SIZE];

    System.out.print("Off to the races! Press enter to make the horses run.");

    String readString = reader.nextLine();
    while(winner!=true){//loop forever until winner
    //begin program
      System.out.print(readString);
      if(readString.equals("")){//when enter is pressed

         for(int i = 0; i<arrRan.length; i++){//loop that adds position when enter is pressed
            arrRan[i] = arrRan[i] + (ran.nextInt(3) + 1); //add to the array in random numbers
            System.out.println("Horse " + (i+1) + ": " + arrRan[i]);//print the contents of the array
         }       
      }//end if
      if(reader.hasNextLine()){
         readString = reader.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please press enter.");
      }
  for(int i = 0; i<arrRan.length; i++){
     if(arrRan[i]>=15){//if a winner is found
        first = first + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        winner = true;

     }

     //if winner is found then look for a 2nd place
     //if there is no position 14 then search for 13, if no 13 then 12. The lowest 2nd place will be in position 12. 
     if(arrRan[i]==14){
        second = second + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        secondPl = true;

     }
     if(arrRan[i]!=14&&arrRan[i]==13){
        second = second + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        secondPl = true;  
     }
     if(arrRan[i]!=13&&arrRan[i]==12){
        second = second + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        secondPl = true;  
     }
     if(arrRan[i]==13){
        third = third + "Horse " + (i+1)+" "; 
     }         
  }
  if(winner==true){
  System.out.println(first);
  System.out.println(second);
  System.out.println(third);
  }      

    }//end while
   }//close main
}//close class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exit from a `for` loop using the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the three best horses by looping through all horses and saving the best ones on the fly. After that you print the result.

Have three variables for the numbers of the three best horses, and three variables for the distance of the three best horses.

In the loop, you check whether the horse you are currently looking at is better than the first, second or third horse. Then you insert it at the corresponding place and shift the other horses down.

At the end, you will have the three best horses with their distance, and can just print them one by one.

Shifting down can be implemented Mike this:

```
int horse1, horse2, horse3, d1, d2, d3;

// Do something...

horse3 = horse2;
d3 = d2;
horse2 = horseNew;
d2 = dNew;
```

You should be able to figure out the shifts when inserting at place one and three.

Comment: This is confusing to me so you have 6 variables and then how do you "shift the other" horses down?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your for loop that checks the winners from first to third place, you can use this: So if there is a winner, the while loop comes out.

```
  winner = checkAndPrintWinner(arrRan);
```

And then to find the winners itself, the below code does sorting to see if there is a winner and if there is, it keeps track of last value so it can do an append or add to new element in the `winners` array. Feel free the print the results in a different way. The code could be optimized a bit more.

```
private static boolean checkAndPrintWinner(int [] data) {
  boolean isWinner = false;
  // Do copy and then Ascending sort
  int results[] = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
  Arrays.sort(results);

  if (results[results.length-1] >= 15) {
    // We have a winner
    isWinner = true;
    String winners[] = new String[3]; // First three winners 
    winners[0] = ""; winners[1] = ""; winners[2] = "";
    int index = 0;
    int total = results.length;
    int lastValue = results[total-1];
    int fromIndex = 0;

    // Start from the back of sorted array where our winners are.
    for (int i = total-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      int nextValue = results[i];

      // if values differ, move on to next winner
      if (lastValue != nextValue) {
        fromIndex = 0;
        index++;
      }
      // we got all three winners, so break
      if (index == 3) break;

      // Get the next winning index
      fromIndex = getHorseIndexForValue(fromIndex, nextValue, data);
      winners[index] += " Horse " + (fromIndex + 1);

      lastValue = nextValue;
      // If winning values are same, next time we want to search from the last found index(fromIndex) + 1.
      fromIndex++;
    }

    System.out.println("Winners: " + Arrays.toString(winners));
  }
  return isWinner;
}

// Get where our horse is based on its score
private static int getHorseIndexForValue(int from, int value, int [] data) {
  for (int i = from; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] == value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; // should never come here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to have many flaws.

- while loop doesn't seem to end
- first to reach 14 may not be the first
- to reach 15, so you should make sure that no duplicate values are
  present in first, second and third first,
- once set should not be set again
- while loop should break once all three are found.

Use break statement to exit the loop

UPDATE : 
Lets assume, horse1 is the only one to reach on or beyond 13. In that case, 
1. IN any iteration, Horse1 = 13, then first = null, second=Horse1, third = Horse1
2. Horse1 = 14, first =  null, second=Horse1, third = horse1
3. Horse1 = 15, first = horse1, second = Horse1, third = Horse1

In the above example, no variable is being re-set to another value as no other horse has reached to a value of 12 or beyond

Hence, possibility of duplicates
Let me know if I got it right

```
for(int i = 0; i<arrRan.length; i++){
     if(arrRan[i]>=15){//if a winner is found
        first = first + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        winner = true;

     }

     //if winner is found then look for a 2nd place
     //if there is no position 14 then search for 13, if no 13 then 12. The lowest 2nd place will be in position 12. 
     if(arrRan[i]==14){
        second = second + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        secondPl = true;

     }
     if(arrRan[i]!=14&&arrRan[i]==13){
        second = second + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        secondPl = true;  
     }
     if(arrRan[i]!=13&&arrRan[i]==12){
        second = second + "Horse " + (i+1)+" ";
        secondPl = true;  
     }
     if(arrRan[i]==13){
        third = third + "Horse " + (i+1)+" "; 
     }         
  }
```

Comment: The while loop ends when a winner is found. The program won't start placing the horses until a winner is found and at this point I am just trying to figure out why the program prints the same horse in multiple positions

Comment: I think you're right that is why it duplicates. I do not know how to fix it though but at least I know why its broken. Thanks!

Comment: if it answers your question, please accept the same. If you can follow my earlier guidelines, you may be able to reach the correct way of implementing this.

Comment: @DosLurez, Instead of making a hardcoded check for 12, 13 or 14 for 2nd and 3rd place, you can instead do the dynamic way.. See my answer